# Only save changes in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel for editing a large XLSX file (~230kb, 20 sheets). They way I do it yet is:

1. load the file (create the PHPExcel object)
2. do the changes on the PHPExcel object
3. overwrite the XLSX file with a new one

This is very slow (~6 seconds), although there are only small changes (some cells in just one worksheet).

Is there a way to save just the **changes** in the file? Or if not, with another library?

Comment: "No", unless you write your own library to do this; because an Excel file is actually a collection of files; and even a small change to an Excel document files can affect perhaps as many as 8-10 of those individual files that then need to be bundled back together again

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it with Spout: https://github.com/box/spout. It should not take more than a second and your code should look like this:

```
$reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::XLSX);
$reader->open('path/to/file/to/read.xlsx');

$writer = WriterFactory::create(Type::XLSX);
$writer->openToFile('path/to/file/to/write.xlsx'); // needs to be different than the one read for now

while ($reader->hasNextSheet()) {
    $reader->nextSheet();

    while ($reader->hasNextRow()) {
        $row = $reader->nextRow();
        // change the row here if needed
        $writer->addRow($row);
    }
}

$reader->close();
$writer->close();

// And at the end, you can replace the old file with the new one:
rename('path/to/file/to/read.xlsx', 'path/to/file/to/write.xlsx');
```

Hope that helps!